# Register REST route with a multi-value parameter

Tags: rest-api

I want the UID parameter of this REST route I'm registering to accept both a single value or multiple values (let's say a comma-separated list, like "800,300,100").

Is there some standard way to do it, or should I take the whole string and manage the commas on my own? Looking around, I find only single-value code samples.

```
  register_rest_route('my-api/', 'subscribe/course-id/(?P<cid>\d+)/user-id/(?P<uid>\w+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my-callback',
    ));
```

Comment: A strong with commas is a single value, and would be registered as a single parameter. Splitting it and interpreting it as multiple value is something to need to handle yourself in your callback (and document, if necessary).

Comment: Got it. I'll change \w+ to [a-zA-Z0-9_,]+ so that it recognizes the comma